# Tiny problem with preg match all

Tags: php, regex

what's the problem with the follow? It does not echo something..

```
$string = '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XBH1dcHoL6Y&rel=0&hl=en_US&feature=player_embedded&­version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390"></embed>'; 

preg_match('#<embed[^>]+>.+?http://www.youtube.com/v/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).+?</embed>#s', $string, $matches); 
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: The problem? You're trying to parse HTML with regexps!

Comment: Well as I read here is a working result http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/echo-youtube-code-from-url-or-shortcode

Comment: that answer is for a different scenario. They're matching `<object>blah</object>`, not `<embed blah></embed>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this: `<embed[^>]+>.+?http`. That means:

1. match the string `<embed`
2. followed by one or more characters that is not `>`
3. followed by a `>`
4. followed by any number of characters (non-greedily)
5. followed by `http`

Your string does not match those criteria because you don't have a `>` before your `http`. If you remove the `[^>]+>` bit your regular expression should match.

Now you know one of the problems with parsing HTML with a regular expression. You shouldn't. You should use a DOM parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

it is actually possible to parse html with regexps. have a look at for example smarty-s source to see how it parses tags :P but it is not the way to do it.

try an xmlparser or domdocument

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('#([\w\-]+){11}?#is', $string, $matches);
```